# Executing multiple Git Command without $ sign

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I have been trying to execute multiple git command

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only master)
```

where a list of modified file names are retrieved using

```
$(git diff --name-only master)
```

and its been archived using

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD
```

I need a way to use it without $ command as I am not able to use this within the cruise control configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent:

```
git diff --name-only master | xargs git archive -o update.zip HEAD
```

Comment: Thank I have tried this too. It seems like not accepting   |  as well :-(

Comment: @hellowahab, seems like some pretty sensible security measures... they just don't want you to execute dynamic stuff, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [config preprocessor](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration_Preprocessor) for cruise control then `$` is a special character which has a meaning to the preprocessor, it can be escaped however:

`\$` is the escape sequence you would need to use, thus allows you to execute the exact same command via cruise control that you have performed in the command prompt.

As such you would be able to use the following:
`git archive -o update.zip HEAD \$(git diff --name-only master)`